# Apache Lounge server is not responding for rpy2 package on windows machine

Tags: r, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi, rpy2

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
```

Apache + mod_wsgi + python 3.x configuration is working pretty nice on my windows machine. It is rpy2 package which is actually giving me trouble. However the same piece of code is working for me in the command line/IDLE.

I tried putting this configuration in the httpd.conf file from the below shared link:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

https://serverfault.com/questions/514242/non-responsive-apache-mod-wsgi-after-installing-scipy

Still no luck..
Code where it's failing:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

def calculate_from_data(self, path):
    pandas2ri.activate()
    r = robjects.r
    print("running R.........")
    filepath = path + os.sep + 'vectorization.R'
    r.source(filepath)
    vectorize = r['vectorize']
    matrix = vectorize(self.base_data.df)
```

Apache should give me the same result as running those code in command line/IDLE gives?. Need help on this please..

For example: piece of code which is executing as expected from CMD/IDLE:

```
import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

print("initializing...")
rinterface.initr()
print("  done.")

print("Mapping the R base package...")
base = importr('base')
print("  done.")
```

output:

```
initializing...
  done.
Mapping the R base package...
  done.
```

But the same code is not working on Apache.